# How can I directly move windows to another viewport, choosing from a list?

Tags: unity, workspaces, viewports

With multiple viewports, you can right click a window and then move it to the viewport right/down, etc.

On *Gnome*, I could send a window directly to *workspace* 1/2/3/4.

Can I implement this in Unity?  Right click the window and send the window to a named or numbered viewport?

Comment: we don't have workspaces anymore. we have viewports (and yes those are different things).

Comment: Right clicking on the window's title bar gives options "Move to another workspace" .  This is already implemented, ever since 13.04 I think

Comment: @serg Haha, oh crap, took me an hour of my life.

Comment: @JacobVlijm still good to see that it can be implemented manually :)

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking on title bar gives options for moving to different workspaces. This functionality is already implemented in Unity and has been for some time.

[image]